# Show/Hide Widgets according to User's Role

Tags: flutter

I am working on an employee scheduling app.

In order to see the employees' availability, I have created a page where an employee may insert his unavailability on a given day due to sickness, etc.

Simultaneously, I want this page to be visible to the admin, in order to have an overview of the status of his employees.

The employee should be only able to add an unavailability reason, but the admin should have an additional right to add a shift to a given employee if he is available.

Do I need to create two separate pages, or is it possible to use the same page and make widgets visible/hide according to a user's role?

If it is possible to use the same page which classes do I need to use for the role distinction?

Note: I read that firebase is the simplest option when authenticating users, thus I am going to use it.

Comment: if I understand you correctly, I think you can use the role of the user as a state in a stateful widget and work with either a [builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Builder-class.html) or an [opacity widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Opacity-class.html)

Comment: @josh By reading the flutter documentation on opacity, it states that I can make a widget invisible to a user. Does this mean that a user can still click it on accident although it is invisible?

Comment: I just saw that there is now a [visibility widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Visibility-class.html). this may suit your needs better. there is also an maintainInteractivity property. So you can decide for yourself whether it is clickable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option I think is to use [IndexedStack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IndexedStack-class.html),

```
 body: IndexedStack(
        index: stackIndex,//0 is for the first and n is for the last
        children: <Widget>[
          Widget1,//index is 0
          Widget2,//index is 1
        ],
      ),
```

You need to only change the index to change body to the next widget(page).

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the user is an admin or employee and render related widgets.if there's nothing to show you can use a empty Container widget.

```
isAdmin ? AdminSpecificWidget():Container();
```